# Copy postgres data files from a broken server to a new server

Tags: postgresql, data

I was running a postgres13 on a ec2 instance.  This instance got corrupt and I lost the sudo access hence I could not login into postgres any more nor read data in tables.

I created another instance from a image taken a week back.  This image has all the data except the ones that got added in the last one week.

I tried copying data from `/var/lib/postgresql/13/main` of the corrupt server and copied them into the new server in the same location.  However, the new server still shows only the old data and not the copied one.

How do I copy the `data files` from corrupt server and restore them in the new server.  Please note I do not have sudo access in the old server though I could copy all the files to the new server.

Comment: Copying was all you did?  You didn't stop the new server before and restart it afterwards?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thank you for your response.  I did shut the server, copied the data files and restarted it....however I am getting a port 5432 conflict error.

Comment: So something is using that port, probably the old server.  I mean the old server process.  Can you reboot that system to be sure?

Comment: Thank you again. when I did pg_lsclusters I could see postgres 9.6 which is up and 13 is down....my database is in ver 13.

Comment: So a conflict between two versions.  Do you need both?  Did you have two versions on the old system?